# Prior Grounding Requirement and Michael Williams

Tags: epistemology

In his book Problems of Knowledge, Michael Williams talks about the *grounding requirement*, which, according to the extended standard analysis, is necessary to say that someone knows something. Williams asserts, however, that this *grounding requirement* (or *intellectualism*) is epistemologically questionable. He says:

> A more interesting thought is that "intellectualism" is questionable
> *from an epistemic standpoint*. For example, by "evidence" we mean known facts that give grounds to inferring further facts. This is what
> we have in mind when we speak of experimental evidence in favour of a
> scientific hypothesis or of the evidence that led the jury to convict.
> Here justification takes the form of an explicit argument. But not all
> justification is like this.
> Many of our beliefs result from the unreflective use of our perceptual
> capacities and, in such cases, talk of evidence sounds strained. Mouse
> droppings are evidence that mice have got into the house: seeing the
> mice themselves run across the floor isn't.

What does he mean with the last sentence about the mouse droppings? That, according to the prior grounding requirement, only something that gives grounds for inferring further facts counts as evidence? And, because seeing mice run across the floor does not give grounds to further inferences, we have already reached the conclusion through observation, which is falliable by nature? But the observation of mouse droppings on the floor is subject to the same perceptual inaccuacies, so I do not understand what he means here.

Comment: Schopenhauer concludes *the will is not reasoning, but an irrational, unconscious urge in relation to which the intellect represents a secondary phenomenon. The will is actually the force at the core of all reality.* Our conscious intellect only occupies a very tiny part of our brain compared to the vast ocean-like subtle habit-forming subconsciousness as emphasized by Carl Jung. A better example than your mouse example could be our perceptions of cats are always not exactly the same then how can we share the same intersubjective term called "cat" *logically*? Actually we *will* to share...

Comment: That's a puzzling comment. I suspect we need more of the context to understand what he's saying.

Comment: @DavidGudeman
Do you mean Double Knot's comment or my question? I have extended the quote and my thoughts to provide more clarity, just in case.

Comment: @DoubleKnot
I do not quite understand what you intend to convey with the Schopenhauer quote. Williams talks about the *unreflective use of our perceptual capacities*. There is no question that our will (or our biases, to use a psychological term) shape our perception. However, I do not see how one could be incentivised to believe that mice are in the house in the given example. In other words, the motivational component seems removed and, to me, it sounds more like an argument about the limits of our perceptual capacities.

Comment: I was talking about your quote from Williams. I can't figure out (even with your extended quote) what he means when he says that a mouse running across the floor is not evidence.

Comment: I believe you already understood the author's intention by your latest edit as the critique of pure reason here is "grounding requirement". Intellectualism demands grounding evidence (fact) in addition to reason. But in the case of "seeing the mice themselves run across the floor" there's no inference but only perception source. Due to commonly understood "unreflective use of our perceptual capacities", this *source* of grounding is problematic as alternatively provoked by my cat example. Indeed in the inferential role semantics of logic any premises/axioms per se have no meaning at all...

Comment: Yes, I do understand now. He criticises the requirement that evidence can only consist of something that starts an inferential chain. This is absurd in the mouse example, where both, the observation of the mouse droppings and seeing mice themselves run across the floor, should give good evidence that mice came into the house. In fact, through common sense, seeing the mice themselves is a stronger reason than the mouse droppings, as both observations are perceptually falliable, but a longer inferential chain is susceptible to more alternative explanations. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DoubleKnot, ah, I see now. I was for some reason reading "got into the house" as "there is a colony of mice currently living in the house", not merely that mice are present in the house right now. That's why I was thinking that seeing mice run across the floor should start a chain of reasoning.